# Why is the initial reputation 1 instead of 0 for registered users?

Tags: discussion, reputation

For any new registered Stack Overflow user, the user will own 1 reputation. Why is the initial reputation 1 instead of 0?

Comment: Think of it as free gift ;)

Comment: Jeff's rationale from the über-meta: [Why does reputation have a lower bound of 1?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1)

Answer (score -8, accepted):

All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1 so this so called 1 reputation is practically 0 reputation.

Also 0 reputation might sound rude.

Comment: That doesn't explain *why* 1 was chosen as the initial and absolute minimum possible reputation, though.

Comment: @Anthony, Edited answer now